# adding a new component and what is Interop.dll file?

Tags: c#, dll, interop, components, dllregistration

I add a component to my project and now in `..\bin\Debug` folder this file 
is added:`Interop.t1.dll`.
i want to make setup file for
my project ,because of Interop file that is created in `..\bin\Debug`
 ,i don't need be worry about registering the component(t1),
is it true?if i should do more task for making setup ,please
guide me.thanks alot...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You added a COM component to your project.  The IDE automatically generated the interop assembly for it.  Yes, you'll need to deploy that DLL along with the EXE.  The greater effort however is in making sure that this COM component gets deployed on the target machine as well.  You'll need the vendor's installer if this is not a one of the COM servers that are available on any Windows machine.  "t1" certainly doesn't sound like a standard one.

Comment: "t1" is not real compnent.if the component isn't available on any Windows machine,what should i do?

Comment: You have to install it of course.  I can't help you find out how to install a component that is not real.

Comment: you mean in every machine that i install setup ,i should  install KDTele compnent at fisrt ,for execute the program correctly.is it true?

Comment: Yes, that's a very non-standard component, the odds it will be present on the target machine are zero.  You no doubt need to purchase a license for every customer, contact the vendor to make a deal.